# Import Stock error: systemException Warning: Undefined array key "source_code"

Tags: magento2, system

I am experiencing this error when Importing stock via CSV file:

systemException
Additional data: Warning: Undefined array key "source_code" in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-import-export/Model/Import/SourceItemConvert.php on line 40

My file passes validation and always fails this.

[image]

Any help appreciated. Also cant find anything in the exception log

Comment: There might be a space in the cell.

Comment: which exact version you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in our project. I fixed it by doing these:

1- TRUNCATE TABLE importexport_importdata;
2- TRUNCATE TABLE import_history;

You can try this please take a backup from your database before making any modifications.

if this answer solved your problem mark it as resolved.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with the Magento inventory module, I am using the same template that I used in version 2.4.6. and now it doesn't work in version 2.4.6-p1, even if you download a file from the current stocks, and then try to upload it, I get the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a hotfix module you can download it from here:

https://github.com/o0mohd0o/ImportExportPatch